# In cocos2d-x 3.0, how can I change the sprite of a progress timer while maintaining the percentage?

Tags: c++, timer, cocos2d-x, sprite, progress

The method below is called after a user action.  The intent of the code is to change the sprite of the progress timer without changing the time remaining.  My code changes the sprite, but it also increases the time remaining on the timer. The amount varies each time, but it always increases.  What am I doing wrong?

Before user action:

[image: Before User Action]

After user action:

[image: After User Action]

```
void TouchScene::switchColors(CustomTimer* centerTimer)
{
    float time = myTimer->getPercentage();
    myTimer->runAction(RemoveSelf::create());
    createCenterTimer(time);
}

void TouchScene::createCustomTimer(float percentage)
{
    myTimer = CustomTimer::create();
    int iRandomColor = getNextColor();
    std::string colorName = getColorName(iRandomColor);
    myTimer->setName(colorName);
    myTimer->setAngle((float)M_PI * 2);
    /*pass the current percentage to the new timer*/
    myTimer->drawTimer(percentage);
    addChild(myTimer, 0);
}

void CustomTimer::drawTimer(float time)
{
    /*removed standard positioning code*/

    /*get the name of the next sprite*/
    std::string name = getName().c_str();
    Sprite *timerSprite = Sprite::create( name + ".png");
    timer = ProgressTimer::create(timerSprite);
    timer->setType( ProgressTimer::Type::RADIAL );
    timer->setReverseDirection(true);

    /*set the timer to pick up where the previous one left off...*/
    timer->setPercentage(time);  //gives inconsistent results
    addChild(timer);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of CustomTimer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to remove current instance of ProgressTimer, just resetting new sprite with different color using `setSprite` on your `CustomTimer` object will work fine. Here is the sample code:

```
void TestGame::drawTimer(float time) {
    Sprite *timerSprite = Sprite::create("blueCircle.png");
    myTimer = ProgressTimer::create(timerSprite);
    myTimer->setPosition(Vec2(100,100));
    myTimer->setType( ProgressTimer::Type::RADIAL );
    myTimer->setReverseDirection(true);
    myTimer->setPercentage(100);
    this->addChild(myTimer);

    myTimer->runAction(ProgressFromTo::create(10, time, 0));

    auto cb = CallFunc::create(CC_CALLBACK_0(TestGame::changeColor, this));
    this->runAction(Sequence::create(DelayTime::create(5), cb, NULL));

}
void TestGame::changeColor() {
    Sprite *timerSprite = Sprite::create("redCircle.png");
    myTimer->setSprite(timerSprite);
}
```